Variable RC high pass filter problem
I'm having an issue with a simple RC HPF. I calculated what max cutoff frequency I want and picked up components accordingly (10kΩ potentiometer and 1nF capacitor). When I feed the signal through it is already filtered with the pot at zero resistance. I'm not sure what am I missing here. Please see the picture of my breadboard layout and video showing what's happening. I also tried grounding the wiper pin but I got no sound at all in that configuration.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-b-plQzMRos !!! PLEASE ADJUST YOUR VOLUME AS THE SOUND COMES SUDDENLY !!!

Your circuit should be connected like this, for it to do what you expect:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your photo shows nothing connected to the black "−" bus bar of the prototyping board. That's one possibility. Another is that it looks like you're using the wrong holes in the prototyping board to connect to the potentiometer pins:

(from robocomp.in)
The two track-end pins are separated by 0.2 inches, which is two holes apart on the prototyping board. The wiper pin is half-way between them. Shift your capacitor one hole to the left.

Hey, thanks. I shifted the cap back as you said and the results are the same. Audio out is already filtered and turning the trim filters it more so I'm still puzzled as from what I understand when the pot is at zero the filter should be open letting through full spectrum of the sound. I also tried grounding the rightmost leg of the pot and the wiper itself - no change (when the right leg is grounded the signal is filtered, when the wiper is grounded there is no sound at all) And the "-" bus is grounded as well. Any other ideas?
